# How can I obtain the corners of a quadrilateral in a binary image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have the following binary image:
[image]

In this binary image, there is a quadrilateral. However, due to poor pre-processing, there are some intervals in the contour of the quadrilateral, and in other words the quadrilateral is not closed. Then my question is how can I obtain the corners of the quadrilateral. If I can obtain the corners, I can perform projective correction on the original image and obtain a image with geometric distortion. Any ideas will be appreciated. The illustration image can be downloaded from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92688392/blob.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to

- first detect the different lines in your image (using for example
  Hough transform),
- keep the 4 ones that make up your quadrilateral
  (by geometric reasoning),
- finally compute their intersections.

This is also a classical way to implement chessboard corner detection in camera calibration routines by the way.

Why do I claim that it is the best? Because it can handle missing corners and noise on the corner positions, since fitting a line will "invent" missing points and average the error among the detected edge pixels.
There is also some "old" (from the 80's or 90's) NASA-funded benchmark for camera calibration that backs up this claim, but it is very hard to find online (I was lucky enough to read a hard copy in one of my previous jobs).

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it is a good idea to perform morphological skeleton before performing Hough transform? Or perform canny detector before Hough? I just want to let Hough transform analysis much easier by doing so.

Comment: No, I believe your actual binary image should be ok.